# how to use html templates in C++ to convert html file to ps in C++

Tags: c++

how to use html templates in C++ to convert html file to ps in C++

Comment: Are you talking about .Net? If not, what HTML templates?

Comment: i am talking about c++, i need to use c++ html template library to convert html into postscript

Comment: @khyathi You didn't really answer, but anyway, if you are looking for HTML parser for C++, check out Mozilla.

Comment: whats mozila ididnt get u can pass the url plz

Comment: its should compile in linux redhat

Comment: @khyathi You are kidding, right? Even if you never heard of Mozilla Firefox, you can just type www.mozilla.com. Anyway, you are interested specifically in this: http://www.mozilla.org/projects/#technologies

Comment: @khyathi: seriously, this is the fourth question about the same thing! All your previous questions have enough information to start making an attempt at it! (side note, no such thing as "HTML templates", there is XSL, which is what I told you to use already!)

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++ library for html formating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041835/c-library-for-html-formating)

Answer (score 1):

This question reminds me very much of this one :

http://groups.google.com/group/comp.object/browse_thread/thread/9384f6c79d253cf3/3aeae8d49982414d?#3aeae8d49982414d

And the answer is : use the system function :

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/

Comment: i am not getting how this can help i need c++ library for reading html template,how can use this in c++ program

Comment: @khyathi To call a program which does that for you. There are probably libraries that might do that, but your question makes no sense. The answer above best suits the question.

Comment: can you tell how to call the template in c++ any code snip with you